# Android indeterminate progress bar between activities

Tags: android

How to get an **indeterminate progress bar** between two activities, I mean, I'm in activity A, show the progress bar, while the progress bar is showing, a new activity B is started and in this activity B I want to close the progress bar. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. An Activity is what holds everything on the screen for your application. If you are "inbetween" two activities then you have no way to control what is on the screen.

You need to put the progress bar into ActivityB, and make it visible by default, then when you are done loading your data make it invisible with

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If your ActivityB is taking a long time to load before showing any Views then it is an indication that you are doing some loading work on the Main thread, that you should isntead be doing in the background, and updating the Views once loading is complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to do so. Starting a new activity is a very fast process, almost instant (unless you onPause method takes very long), so the progress bar will never be shown.

That being said, there is a hacky way to get a progress bar to be shown between activities
you call ProgressActivity(that you create) from ActivityA then after waiting for some time (delayed runnable) you call ActivityB. This does nothing constructive and should not be used.